# I need to make array from string (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have followed string:

```
$str = "  father    mother brother   sister  ";
```

and I need to get array that contains 4 elements: "father", "mother", "brother" and "sister"

Comment: what are the separators between the words in the string? space? tab? multiple spaces? are they always the same etc?

Comment: Seperators are always only spaces. I tried exploade, but I get array with more than 4 elements, wich most of them, are empty.

Comment: @user3036943 `preg_split` is the way to go! You can look it up in the manual

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "  father    mother brother   sister  ";
    $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($parts);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => father [1] => mother [2] => brother [3] => sister )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple, perhaps variable length spaces between words the simplest way is with `preg_split`:

```
$array = preg_split('/ +/', "  father    mother brother   sister  ", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Test:

```
php > $array = preg_split('/ +/', "  father    mother brother   sister  ", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
php > var_dump($array);
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "father"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "mother"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "brother"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "sister"
}
```

If you want to split by any whitespace (including tabs and new lines) you can try:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s+/', "  father    mother brother   sister  ", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string in pieces separated by space character () then pass the returned array to [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty pieces (your string contains multiple consecutive separators) and finally use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get rid of the keys (they remain sparse after `array_filter()`) and renumber the items starting from `0`:

```
$str = "  father    mother brother   sister  ";
$array = array_values(array_filter(explode(' ', $str)));

print_r($array);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => father
    [1] => mother
    [2] => brother
    [3] => sister
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = "  father    mother brother   sister  ";
$tmpArr = explode(' ',$str);
$newArr = array();
foreach ($tmpArr AS $v) {if (!empty($v)) {$newArr[] = $v;}}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$result = explode(' ',$str);
array_walk($result,'trim');
function trim($str){
   $str = trim($str);
}
?>
```